# Dúvida sobre funções e classes

Tags: c++

```
class base_token
{

    public:

        typedef enum {  t_invalid_token=0, t_symbol, t_integer, t_literal,

                        t_punctuation, t_keyword

                     } type_of_token;

    private:

        type_of_token token_type;

    public:

        base_token(type_of_token token) : token_type(token) { };

        type_of_token get_type() { return token_type; };

        virtual const char *  parse_token(const char * s) = 0;

};
```

Essa linha esta dizendo o que (sintaxe)?

```
base_token(type_of_token token) : token_type(token) { };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou dar uma resposta pensando do ponto de vista semântico, acredito que este seja o objetivo da sua pergunta. Se não o for, eu edito ela e coloco a análise sintática.

Essa linha declara um construtor para a classe `base_token`. Os construtores são métodos que possuem o mesmo nome da classe, não retornam nenhum tipo (nem mesmo `void`).

Este construtor exige um único parâmetro, do tipo `type_of_token`. O nome do parâmetro é `token`.

O construtor inicializa o campo `token_type` (declarado com acesso `private`) com o valor passado no argumento `token`.

O corpo do método é vazio.

Este construtor (nestas condições específicas), é equivalente a:

```
base_token(type_of_token token) {
    token_type = token;
}
```

Ambos, no contexto da classe exibida, possuem o mesmo efeito.

Vale ressaltar que esta é uma pergunta de C++, não C.